# How do I type onSuccess data in React Query?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-query

I have API call function (`httpClient` is `axios` instance)

```
interface IRegisterResponse {
  accessToken: string;
}

export const register = async ({
  name,
  password,
  token,
}: IRegisterParams) =>
  await httpClient.post<IRegisterResponse>('register', {
    name,
    password,
    token,
  });
```

And I have useMutation hook that handles this API call form me

```
  const { mutate: registerMutation } = useMutation(
    ['register'],
    register,
    {
      onSuccess: ({ accessToken }) => console.log(accessToken),
    }
  );
```

But in `onSuccess` callback it highlights `accessToken` with message `Property 'accessToken' does not exist on type 'AxiosResponse<IRegisterResponse, any>'`

What am I doing wrong and how should I type it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning axios response, not data

```
onSuccess: ({ data: { accessToken } }) => console.log(accessToken)
```

or

```
export const register = async ({
  name,
  password,
  token,
}: IRegisterParams) =>
  (await httpClient.post<IRegisterResponse>('register', {
    name,
    password,
    token,
  })).data;
```

Comment: Damn, so stupid from my side. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: the second option is much preferred because the first option will store the whole axios response in the query cache, which contains some non-serializable stuff.